# Angular deployment routing location issue

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am using location to go to previous page in Angular project.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common'

constructor(private location: Location) {}

backbutton() {
    //routing back using this.location
}
```

Disregard any syntax error. As the code is working perfectly in local. However, the deployed project crashes the app. Happens only in deployment. How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe using window.location instead. There's not a whole lot of info here to go on so if that doesn't help maybe you could provide more?

Comment: Can you paste the error that is caused in production?